# Div-(Table)Layout breaks when surrounded by link

Tags: html, css

I have a problem and I tried so many hours to solve this, so I wanted to ask you if you have an idea for me.

I made a Div-Table-Layout and everything ist ok now.

Now I want to make a whole row clickable with just css Style and tried the following in the first row:

```
<a><tr><td></td></tr></a>
```

When I do this, the columns aren't as wide as before I entered the a-tag.

Is there any way to do this?

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <a href="#" class="divTableRow">
        <div class="col-xs-2 divTableCell">21</div>
        <div class="divTableCell divTableCellRight col-xs-10">Test</div>
    </a>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="col-xs-2 divTableCell ">21</div>
      <div class="divTableCell divTableCellRight col-xs-10">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="col-xs-2 divTableCell ">21</div>
      <div class="divTableCell divTableCellRight col-xs-10">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9b905xry/2/

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the div tag and add divTableRow to anchortag... 
Hope this will help you..

```css
.divTable {
  display: table;
  width: calc(100% - 30px);
  margin: 15px;
}

.divTableRow {
  display: table-row;

}

.divTableRow:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background: #e0e0e0;
}

.divTableRow:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
}

.divTableCell,
.divTableHead {
  height: 96px;
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  float: none;
}

.divTableCellLeft {
  text-align: center;
}

.divTableCellRight {
  text-align: left;
}

.divTableHeading {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableFoot {
  background-color: #EEE;
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.divTableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
  <div class="divTableBody">
    <a href="" class="divTableRow">
        <div class="col-xs-2 divTableCell">21</div>
        <div class="divTableCell divTableCellRight col-xs-10">Test</div>
      </a>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="col-xs-2 divTableCell ">21</div>
      <div class="divTableCell divTableCellRight col-xs-10">Test</div>
    </div>
    <div class="divTableRow">
      <div class="col-xs-2 divTableCell ">21</div>
      <div class="divTableCell divTableCellRight col-xs-10">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you might be going about this the wrong way I'm afraid. I really think you need to just make an *html table* (since this looks very much like tabular data) and simply have links in the table cells.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">21</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href="#">21</a></td>
      <td><a href="#">Test</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```